# @Version throw IncompatibleClassChangeError during insert

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have got problem with optimisticlock by @Version in entity

Without @Version all operation work fine, but i need versioning and locking.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person  
{  
    .............. others fields and id

   @Version
   @Column(name = "_version", columnDefinition = "integer DEFAULT 0", nullable = false)
   private Integer version;
}
```

And create entity code with `@Transaction`:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Pike");

personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);
```

And simple repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

And this code throw during create Person throw:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: null
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$$Lambda$805/2119034561.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:230) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:504) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$$Lambda$731/1432027166.proceedWithInvocation(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Why this error is throw ?

I cant see bug and this is standard code for optimistic lock.

My project i use:

- Spring boot: 2.0.4.RELEASE
- Spring version: 5.0.2.RELEASE
- hibernate-core: 5.4.1.Final
- postgresql jdbc: 42.2.5

I did not find a similar problem in internet

Comment: hi, have you already found the solution to this problem?

Comment: @pero_hero nope

Comment: we have the same problem, but it is happens only after two or three days in production and after a tomcat restart it is gone. no clue what it could be ...we looked at all dependencies if there is version mismatch but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because the version is on _version column and no value is set for that column.

Setting a value for that column might resolve the issue.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Pike");
person.setVersion(1);// Or any meaningful value there
```